# AES 256 privacy with Adventnet Java API - traps not received

Tags: java, aes, snmp, snmp-trap

I am using Adventnet 4.0.0 API to receive traps. When AES 128 is used as privacy authentication it is successfully received, whereas when I change to use AES 256 it is not receiving. But Wireshark is able to receive and decode properly.

Any thing I am missing or Adventnet 4.0.0 is not capable of handling AES 256?

Comment: Have you installed the unlimited crypto policy files?

Comment: no.. i didnt knew that

Comment: even after unlimited crypto policy files installed, it is not working? how to enable adventnet logs?

Comment: Haven't got a clue about that. Small note, if I fire "Adventnet 4.0.0 API" into Google, this post comes up first. But note that AES-128 is pretty secure as block cipher. You probably spend your time better elsewhere if you want to upgrade security.

Answer (score 0):

The [WebNMS page for the Java SNMP API](http://www.webnms.com/snmp/index.html) lists the supported encryption schemes:

SNMPv3 security: Support for HMAC-SHA-96, HMAC-MD5-96, CBC-DES, CBC-3DES, CFB-AES-128, CFB-AES-192, CFB-AES-256 bit encryption.

If you don't think it's working like it should, it's always worth shooting off an email [to their support crew.](http://www.webnms.com/support.html)

Hard to say more than that without seeing your code.